# How to update certain values of a php date string?

Tags: php, html, date

I have some date string values that I want to be able to update for checking against in some conditional statements. I want to update the hour, minute and seconds values to be at 23:59:59.

Say I have the variable $value which prints to

```
2017-03-08 00:00:00
```

How can I update the value to be

```
2017-03-08 23:59:59
```

?

Answer (score 1):

Use DateTime.

```
$dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s',$value);
$dateTime->setTime(23,59,59);
$value = $dateTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

You could do many more things with the DateTime class.

Comment: Most likely you could do your conditional checking with the DateTime class instead of the $value string

Answer (score 0):

Hi there this is the code below which you can use to update the time value:

your variable in php:

```
$value = "2017-03-08 00:00:00";
```

the html tag like so:

```
<input type="datetime-local" name="date" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d\TH:i:s", strtotime($value)); ?>" />
```

This tag also generates a date and time picker, assuming you a running a compatible browser.

Note: In the future please show us your work and what you have achieved because you cannot expect someone to do it all for you, good luck!

Answer (score -1):

In this simple case, you could probably leverage `strtotime` to get what you want:

```
$myDate = '2017-03-08 00:00:00';
$myTime = strtotime($myDate) + 86399;
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $myTime);
```

Though in more difficult cases it would probably be better to use PHP's DateTime class:

```
$myDate = '2017-03-08 00:00:00';
$dt = new DateTime($myDate);
// Subtract one second
$dt->add(new DateInterval('PT86399S'));
// Output formatted result
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

You could also look into [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) for handling all of your date / time needs.